# Design a column using only CSS backgrounds

Tags: css, background

Is it possible to design a centered column in the body background using only CSS?

This is what I have already done:

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/500x10);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

My solution above already works properly, but **I want to get rid of that external image** and use only CSS properties.

Basically I would like to achieve this:

- colored body background
- a white, full-height, fixed-width column in the middle

Please don't recommend to change the HTML because it's not what I am asking: I would like to know if I can achieve that **using only CSS**.

Basically I wonder if I can **draw a "green - white (500px) - green" background (on a single DOM element) using only CSS background / gradients / multiple CSS backgrounds**.

Comment: maybe use a v e r y wide colored L/R border? First thing that popped up in my head...

Comment: Or a linear-gradient?

Comment: @RenevanderLende Thanks for the ideas. Borders unfortunately would change the layout... Do you think it's possible with linear gradients or multiple backgrounds? e.g. green body with 500px white column in the middle. From what I have found I can't specify the white-color width in px, only as a percentage

Comment: please add some CSS and HTML to work with and see how you implement constraints...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy with mulitple background:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(green 0 0) right,
    linear-gradient(green 0 0) left;
  background-size:calc(50% - 250px) 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Also like this:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(white 0 0) center/500px 100% no-repeat
    green;
}
```

Another one:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg,
       green   calc(50% - 250px),
       white 0 calc(50% + 250px),
       green 0);
}
```

Box-shadow can also do the job here:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  box-shadow:
    green calc(50vw - 250px) 0 0 inset,
    green calc(250px - 50vw) 0 0 inset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to accomplish this through the :after property of the body tag. Through CSS itself as seen below:

```
body:after {
    content: " ";
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1):
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto; // centering the after DOM element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add styles for `html` tag? It makes your problem to be easier to solve. Also, you don't have to change any html format.

```css
html {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```